# Difference in IE and other browsers' handling of javascript object referencing

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, object

In FireFox and Chrome I can reference object values as such:

```
key = value[0].name
```

But this errors in IE 8, saying "value[0].name" is null.
Any idea to why this is happening?

Full code:

```
     $.each(data, function(key, value){
         key = value[0].name.replace(' ', '');
         var original = $('.'+key+'Link').attr('href');
         var updated = original + '&browseItem='+(this[0]).id;
         $('.'+key+'Link').attr('href', updated);
      });
```

and "data" id the object derived from the JSON string:

```
    [[{"name": "Due", "id": 9}], [{"name": "Fine", "id": 10}], [{"name": "Property Lien", "id": 11}]]
```

**EDIT:**
It seems like it was a problem with caching. Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: Are you *sure* that that's what the "data" object looks like?  If it did, that code would work just fine in IE8.

Comment: What does `alert(JSON.stringify(value))` show in IE8?

Comment: Works for me on IE8. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/4GxGG/1/

Comment: Thanks again for all the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
key = (value[0] || value).name.replace(' ', '');
```

It seems `value` is already the array element you need